# Can Cuda make a finding of combinations faster?

Tags: cuda

I am wondering if Cuda would be useful for this type of problem(and how to approach it in Cuda).  Basically I have been using python to find combinations of a list but as the data gets large I'm thinking running it on a gpu maybe an interesting idea.

Say I have a list `[1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8]` and I want only `7` combinations then I would get:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8)
(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

As the data gets larger it takes a long time.  I have been using `itertools.combinations` which abstracts everything from me so if I try to program this myself is there any resources or proxy code I can look at? Most of the algorithms related to combinations are recursive and my Cuda card does not support recursions.

Any suggestion/tips on where to start?

Comment: This is a really, really, really broad question. Have you done any research into the subject? What did you find? What do you *really* want to know?

Comment: @talonmies I have looked for sample code for the last day and couldn't find anything(other than one site that had it wrapped in R which I don't understand).  I re-read cuda by example to see if there was anything I can use as a proxy to this problem(unable to), and I'm reading Cuda gems so see if there's anything in there.  My question is basically is this possible and what steps could I take to achieve it.  Do you have any suggestions of how I could narrow this down so its not so broad(I thought my example was specific)?

Comment: Forget code. What about in the computer science literature?

Comment: @talonmies I didn't look there. I don't think I own any..most of my books are on languages(java,cuda,python,etc..). Are you referring to book on algorithms or is there something else you think would be helpful for this task?

Comment: I am talking about journal articles and papers aka "the scientific literature" (hint: google scholar is a very useful resource). You aren't likely to make much progress without an algorithm (if it exists), and that is where to look to find one.

Comment: Thanks so much @talonmies I predict after following your advice my SO questions will be reduced by 50%(until I find an algorithm to increase it again :-)  I didn't use google scholar at all, I typically just searched this site,google, github for code so I can try to follow the logic. I'll give your approach a try. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a small CUDA project that does bin packing by trying permutations:

http://www.dahlsys.com/software/fill_media/index.html

Comment: Thanks Roger.  I'll  study your approach.  I'm not doing permutations though I'm doing only combinations, but I'll get ideas of how to structure the program. Thanks, I am enjoying reading your code(your comments are very helpful)

Comment: Thanks. I wrote that a couple of years ago, so I took a look at it now to see if it still makes sense to me. I found that I copy the entire working set for the block in each thread, which is crazy and probably the reason that I had noted that instruction throughput is very low. That's the `memcpy()` in the kernel. It should be refactored so that each thread does a different section. I would also try to use some atomic operation to select the best result for each block.